# How to efficiently split the time series dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, conv-neural-network

So I am a beginner in Python and have been recently working on a project which has a time series ECG values for patients. For every patient, there are approximately 3000000 values in the ECG array, where batches of size 6000 represent a minute's recordings. There is another array named 'annotations' that I have, that labels whether in that particular minute the patient had an apneic event or not. So I have to basically split the 3000000 sized list into a list of lists where each list is of size 6000 and I have to pass this as input to a 1D Convolutional Neural Network with the y_train as the annotation for that particular minute. This procedure I have to do for 35 patients. I tried writing a code which splits the large list into list of lists using the following code.

```
chunks = [data[x:x+6000] for x in range(0, len(data), 6000)]
```

However this takes a lot of time for only a single patient. Is there any better way I can deal with my dataset? That is, How can I convert my 35 lists (1 for every patient) into list of lists for every minute, which will act as my X_train and also generate a list of annotations for all 35 patients which will act as my Y_train.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With data of this size, I strongly suggest you look at using `numpy`. I am guessing that your neural network library probably uses `numpy`, so this would interact well, but since you haven't said what library you are using I cannot be certain.

If you have your data in a `numpy` array, then you can pass slices of that array to the network for each minute, without pre-calculating them, with something like

```py
for start in range(0, len(data), 6000):
    out = conv_neural_net(data[start:start + 6000])
    # Do whatever with the output here
```

`numpy` exists for performing number-crunching on large numeric data sets much faster than is possible with raw Python, so is definitely worthwhile for your case.